# Partition not shown in Disk Utility

Tags: macos, macbook, boot-camp, partition-recovery, disk-utility

My MacBook Pro 2012 has 500 GB of HDD out of which 250 GB were used to install Windows 10. Today, I tried deleting the Windows 10 partition using Boot Camp. In the middle of the deleting process, my MacBook went to sleep and the recovery process could not be completed.

Now I am not able to see the other partition in Disk Utility. Is there any way to get back the other partition?

**Output of diskutil list:**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.3 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.3 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Untitled                235.9 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.2 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                507.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: In Disk Utililty, have you opened "View" ==> "Show All Devices"?

Comment: "Test Disk" can run under Windows, Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, SunOS and __MacOS X__ https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk Tested and Trusted! This can retrieve hard disk partitions others cannot. Worked wonders for me.

Comment: @vssher I have opened "View" ==> "Show All Devices" but second partition is not visible. I will try Test Disk.

Comment: @vssher I tried that but it shows "No harddisk found"

Comment: Have you tried changing data/power cables. I have had that happen to me quite a few times in a Windows machine. Drives dissappear, fail, machine stalls, etc. Could be a failing hard disk. Can you try it in another machine?

Comment: @vssher It's not an external hard disk. It's an internal hard disk in a Mac Book Pro. I can't open it and there is just one hard disk with 2 partitions.

Comment: Could it be that the partition was successfully deleted, and now it is unallocated space? I'm unfamiliar with MacOS and the disk utility is uses. But, obviously the drive is detected as 500GB and there's a 250GB partition, but it says nothing about the other 250GB. This makes me think it's unallocated.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend giving [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/hdm-mac/) a try. You can download a fully-functional trial version. I've used it on multiple occasions to resize and delete the BOOTCAMP partition and reallocate space without any issues on my 2015 MBA.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you share the **Graphical View** of **Disk Partitioning** ?
You can try booting into [Kyhi's Recovery Media](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/27180-windows-10-recovery-tools-bootable-rescue-disk.html) which is based on **Win 10 PE**. You have **Partition Wizard** on that which will show each & every partition on the disk. Try **x64** bit version.

Its very potential recovery disk but based on windows. Try your luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems BootCamp Assistant actually has successfully deleted the partition. Since you knew you were using it to delete the partition already, I'm going to guess that by "get back the other partition" you actually meant "reclaim the space for macOS" and not "restore the Windows files lost when the partition was deleted."

To do that most reliably, you'll need to boot to recovery mode. Restart your computer and hold `cmd + R` until you see the Apple logo. Once recovery loads, click on Disk Utility, select your hard drive, and click Partition. (Pretend that my 32GB Samsung Flash Drive is your hard drive in the photos)
[image: Select Drive and Partition]
You may see a warning about "Apple File System Space Sharing" – click Partition, not Add Volume. 
[image: Select Partiton]
Select the "Free space" partition, click the minus sign to remove the free space, which will automatically expand the Macintosh HD APFS Container to fill the rest of the space. The partition should now be 500GB in size. Once you're done, click Apply.
[image: Select and Remove Free Space]
[image: Check and Apply]
It should do its thing, and once completed, you can restart normally. Your Macintosh HD should be back to its full size!